# Are the seven stages of understanding existence as per Advaita correlated to the seven chakras?

Tags: advaita, consciousness, chakras

I was wondering about the correlation between the seven stages of understanding existence as per Advaita and the seven chakras.

1. The universe as it is- Root Chakra
2. The play of the elements- Sacral Chakra
3. The play of maya- Solar Plexus
4. The play of consciousness- Heart Chakra
5. Appearance in consciousness- Throat Chakra
6. Pervasion of Consciousness- Third Eye
7. Consciousness only- Crown Chakra

Basically we go from seeing existence as the universe as we see it, to eventually realizing it is consciousness alone. Do these realizations correlate to the different centers of consciousness(chakras) we have?